# Error loading the report template:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'head'. One

Tags: java, delphi

i'm newer in jasper reports.i've some problem when i call iReport from jsp....some error occurs at run time as like below :-

Error loading the report template:
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'head'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":field, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":sortField, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is expected.

if anypne know plz help me.
& can give me answer on my email id:-
poonam_jagtap20@rediffmail.com
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is a question of Delphi? Jasper Reports is a JAVA tool.